# How do I link the previous value for a given class using constructors?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

The following is my class template :

```
class vector
{
    int num;
    int *ele;

public:

    vector();
    vector(int);
    vector(vector&);

    void get();
    void print();
};
```

The input format is given as `n` and `a1, a2...., an` which are all integers. And the main function looks like:

```
int main()
{
    vector v1, v2,v3;

    v1.get();
    v1.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

How do I construct an array(sort of) using the given three constructors, I tried the following code but I am nowhere close unless I declare an array and `ele` points to the first address.

```
void vector::get(){
    cin >> num;

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        int tmp;
        cin >> tmp;
        ele = &tmp;

        vector();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your book say about `operator new[]`?

Comment: A generic vector class needs to manage _storage_ for vector elements. This storage can be allocated by [`operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) (not to be confused with `new` _expression_), or with help of _allocators_ (as `std::vector` does). Then, once you have a storage, you can initialize (construct) elements inside it. Note that this is by far not a programming task for C++ beginners.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thank you for your help, doing `ele = new int[num]` solved my problem.